# Extract x columns with argparse python

Tags: python, argparse

I have a file.csv file with thousands of rows and columns. I want to extract x columns from this file.csv. I'm using argparse for this.

here is my code:

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd

def create_parser():
     #
    parser.add_argument('--n', '--names-list', nargs='+' ,help='columns name')
    #to be able to pass a list- of arguments for column extract.
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args
```

this is the function for extracting columns. I have 2 arguments that I want and the rest the user will pass through the cmd.

```
def extract_columns(the_file_name_to_read_from, where_to_extract, *args):
    column_name = []
    x=args
    column_name.extend(x)
    df = pd.read_csv(the_file_name_to_read_from, sep=';',usecols=column_name, engine='python')
    df.to_csv(where_to_extract, sep=';', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = create_parser()
    extract_columns(str(arguments.file_extract), str(arguments.extract_to), str(arguments.n))
```

cmd command:

```
python file.py --file_extract some_File.csv --extract_to new_File someNewFile.csv --n first_column last_column
```

first_column and last_column are the column names that I want to extract from the file- someFile.csv and past them in new_File.csv.

I'm getting an error:

```
Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ["['frist_column', 'last_column']"]
```

Comment: Why did you do `str(arguments.n)`?  You want the names as a list, not a string.  Just pass `n=arguments.n`, then have `n=[]` as a parameter in `extract_columns`.  `str(arguments.extract_to)` doesn't make sense, either.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I'm using str() because I want to be able to pass the folder path also.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying to do.

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--file-extract', help='source file name')
    parser.add_argument('--extract-to', help='destination file name')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--names-list', nargs='+' ,help='columns name')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args

def extract_columns(the_file_name_to_read_from, where_to_extract, column_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(the_file_name_to_read_from, sep=';',usecols=column_name, engine='python')
    df.to_csv(where_to_extract, sep=';', index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    arguments = create_parser()
    extract_columns(arguments.file_extract, arguments.extract_to, arguments.names_list)
```

Usage:

```
python file.py --file_extract some_File.csv --extract_to someNewFile.csv -n first_column -n last_column
```

If you really want to specify multiple column names without the `-n` each time, then you need to make then positional parameters, not keyword.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same error. also cleaned all the other functions, and copy-paste to your code.

Comment: Are you sure your CSV file is using semi-colon as a separator, even on the first line?  That's what you're telling `read_csv`.  This code works for me.

Comment: Hi, it was my wrong, I removed the sep and it runs. but it only prints the last argument(column) I pass. like: 'first_colum' 'last_column' it will print only the 'last_column'

Comment: It's accepting as much as names as you want but using only the last one.

Comment: Hi, the reason why it was overriding is that you used -n first_column -n second_column while we are using nargs = '+'. to use -n and -n the action needs to be action = 'append'. thanks you for your help!